# Stanford NLP Sentiment, sentences in a new line

Tags: annotations, newline, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I'm trying to use Stanford NLP Sentiment Analysis on a file with a new sentence in each line using this command:

```
C:\Users\alonr\IdeaProjects\stanford-corenlp-full-2014-08-27>java -cp "*" -mx2g
edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentPipeline -input TEXT -output PROBABILITIES -file
my_file.txt
```

Unfortunately it doesn't recognize the line brakes in the file as sentence brakes. How can I make it to do so?

Comment: Maybe it doesn't recognize line breaks because your file uses Windows line break ('\r\n') which are 2 characters. You could try to open this file with an advanced text editor like NotePad++ for example, and replace '\r\n' by '\n'.

Answer (score 0):

The main program `SentimentPipeline` isn't set up to allow for changing sentence-splitters. If you're using Stanford CoreNLP, however: you could run through the main CoreNLP pipeline instead with the `-ssplit.eolonly` flag:

```
java -cp "*" -mx2g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP \
    -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,parse,sentiment -ssplit.eolonly \
    -inputFile my_input.txt -outputFormat text -outputFile my_file.txt
```